# VBA Word: conditional text replacement

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a macro that successfully searches a replaces a series of words in a document with this code:

```
'define array1 with words I want replaced
'define array2 with words I want to replace with so that they have the same index
'loop through array and search and replace
with application.activedocument.content.find
for i=1 to 565
.text=array1(i)
.replacement.text=array2(i)
.wrap=wdfindcontinue
.format=false
.matchcase=false
.matchwholeword=true
.matchwildcards=false
.matchallwordsforms=false
.matchsoundslike=false
.matchsuffix=true
.matchprefix=true
.execute replace:=wdreplaceall
next
end with
```

I want to change the functionality so that it won't replace the word if it is the first word in the line, however I realize that the find function doesn't work line by line, or allow conditional testing of properties, so I think the best approach is for me to change the range that my function operates on to exclude the first word in each line.

So instead of ActiveDocument.Content.Find I need ActiveDocument.Range defined somehow so that it excludes the first word of each line.

Does anyone know how to define the range so that it excludes the first word of each line.

Thanks

Comment: did you find the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of you application and by "first word in the line" i assume you meant first word of a paragraph, but this works to apply the search to the entire paragraph (except the first word)

```
'Array position 0    1    2    3    4
array1 = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
array2 = Array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

For p = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
   'Seelcting the paragraph
   ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(p).Range.Select
   'Checking if the paragraph is not a blank line
    If Len(Selection) > 1 Then
        'Moving to begining of the paragraph
        Selection.HomeKey
        'Moving one word to the left
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        'Selecting the rest of the paragraph
        Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdParagraph
        'Setting the selection as a Bookmark
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="TempBM"

        For i = 0 To 4
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = array1(i)
                .Replacement.Text = array2(i)
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = False
                         'Replace that text
                Do While .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
                  'Reselect the Bookmark
                  Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="TempBM"
                Loop

            End With
        Next
        'Deleting Bookmark
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TempBM").Delete
    End If
Next
```

For a test it change this (I added the 1 to the first word to verify it ignores it:

> 1This is a test        1         2        3        4       5
>
> 1This is a test        1         2        3        4       5

to:

> 1This is a test        one         two        three        four       five
>
> 1This is a test        one         two        three        four       five